# Pandas cant read csv file that has missing data

Tags: pandas, csv

`carsmissing=pd.read_csv("carsalesmissing.csv",delimiter=',',na_values=['NaN'])`

Pandas cannot read it as it has missing values in few columns

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file?

Comment: Make,Colour,Odometer,Doors,Price
Toyota,White,150043,4,"$4,000"
Honda,Red,87899,4,"$5,000"
Toyota,Blue,,3,"$7,000"
BMW,Black,11179,5,"$22,000"
Nissan,White,213095,4,"$3,500"
Toyota,Green,,4,"$4,500"
Honda,,,4,"$7,500"
Honda,Blue,,4,
Toyota,White,60000,,
,White,31600,4,"$9,700"    The ,, represents null values

Comment: I tested it here with the sample data you sent me and it worked just fine. Does the `.csv` open fine in Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: The csv files opened in excel